# ImportError: cannot import name 'deprecated' from 'typing_extensions'

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, spacy

I want to download spacy, but the version of typing-extensions is lowered in the terminal:

```
ERROR: pydantic 2.3.0 has requirement typing-extensions>=4.6.1, but you'll have typing-extensions 4.4.0 which is incompatible.
ERROR: pydantic-core 2.6.3 has requirement typing-extensions!=4.7.0,>=4.6.0, but you'll have typing-extensions 4.4.0 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: typing-extensions
  Attempting uninstall: typing-extensions
    Found existing installation: typing-extensions 4.7.1
    Uninstalling typing-extensions-4.7.1:
      Successfully uninstalled typing-extensions-4.7.1
Successfully installed typing-extensions-4.4.0
```

Next I want to install the language pack `python -m spacy download en`, but another error occurs：

```
(base) E:\Anaconda>python -m spacy download en
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\confection\__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    from pydantic.v1 import BaseModel, Extra, ValidationError, create_model
  File "E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pydantic\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from . import dataclasses
  File "E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pydantic\dataclasses.py", line 11, in <module>
    from ._internal import _config, _decorators, _typing_extra
  File "E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pydantic\_internal\_config.py", line 9, in <module>
    from ..config import ConfigDict, ExtraValues, JsonEncoder, JsonSchemaExtraCallable
  File "E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pydantic\config.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .deprecated.config import BaseConfig
  File "E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pydantic\deprecated\config.py", line 6, in <module>
    from typing_extensions import Literal, deprecated
ImportError: cannot import name 'deprecated' from 'typing_extensions' (E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\typing_extensions.py)
```

My current python version is 3.7, should I update it? Or is there any better solution? I'm a newbie in this area, thank you all！

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `typing_extensions==4.7.1`

try :

```
pip install typing_extensions==4.7.1 --upgrade
```

I also suggest you to upgrade your python version from `3.7` to `3.10` or `3.11`

See a relevant answer:

https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/discussions/9808

Comment: I really appreciate your advice; it has been very helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade typing-extensions using the following:

```
pip install typing_extensions>=4.5 --upgrade
```

This is because `depricated` might require `>=4.5` of `typing-extensions`. Restart your Python kernel after that. This worked for me. I was seeing the same issue with '**override**' as `Cannot import name 'override'`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error on colab, with restarting session and running !pip install -U pandas-profiling I could resolve the error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).