# Databricks ImportError: cannot import name 'override' from 'typing_extensions'

Tags: dependencies, databricks, importerror, llama

I am trying to use a databricks notebook to finetune the Llama2 model. The code for this is [here](https://github.com/databricks/databricks-ml-examples/blob/master/llm-models/llamav2/llamav2-7b/06_fine_tune_qlora.py). I'm running into an error at lines 219-231:

```
from trl import SFTTrainer

max_seq_length = 512

trainer = SFTTrainer(
    model=model,
    train_dataset=dataset,
    peft_config=peft_config,
    dataset_text_field="text",
    max_seq_length=max_seq_length,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    args=training_arguments,
)
```

I am getting the error

> ImportError: cannot import name 'override' from 'typing_extensions' (/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/typing_extensions.py)

The full stack trace is below.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
File <command-3349581073491723>, line 1
----> 1 from trl import SFTTrainer
      3 max_seq_length = 512
      5 trainer = SFTTrainer(
      6     model=model,
      7     train_dataset=dataset,
   (...)
     12     args=training_arguments,
     13 )

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-8a237d14-25f4-4066-b47f-e8a95f2342d9/lib/python3.10/site-packages/trl/__init__.py:15
      8 from .import_utils import is_diffusers_available, is_peft_available, is_wandb_available, is_xpu_available
      9 from .models import (
     10     AutoModelForCausalLMWithValueHead,
     11     AutoModelForSeq2SeqLMWithValueHead,
     12     PreTrainedModelWrapper,
     13     create_reference_model,
     14 )
---> 15 from .trainer import (
     16     DataCollatorForCompletionOnlyLM,
     17     DPOTrainer,
     18     IterativeSFTTrainer,
     19     PPOConfig,
     20     PPOTrainer,
     21     RewardConfig,
     22     RewardTrainer,
     23     SFTTrainer,
     24 )
     27 if is_diffusers_available():
     28     from .models import (
     29         DDPOPipelineOutput,
     30         DDPOSchedulerOutput,
     31         DDPOStableDiffusionPipeline,
     32         DefaultDDPOStableDiffusionPipeline,
     33     )

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-8a237d14-25f4-4066-b47f-e8a95f2342d9/lib/python3.10/site-packages/trl/trainer/__init__.py:40
     38 from .dpo_trainer import DPOTrainer
     39 from .iterative_sft_trainer import IterativeSFTTrainer
---> 40 from .ppo_config import PPOConfig
     41 from .ppo_trainer import PPOTrainer
     42 from .reward_trainer import RewardTrainer, compute_accuracy

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-8a237d14-25f4-4066-b47f-e8a95f2342d9/lib/python3.10/site-packages/trl/trainer/ppo_config.py:22
     19 from typing import Literal, Optional
     21 import numpy as np
---> 22 import tyro
     23 from typing_extensions import Annotated
     25 from trl.trainer.utils import exact_div

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-8a237d14-25f4-4066-b47f-e8a95f2342d9/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tyro/__init__.py:4
      1 from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
      3 from . import conf as conf
----> 4 from . import extras as extras
      5 from ._cli import cli as cli
      6 from ._fields import MISSING as MISSING

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-8a237d14-25f4-4066-b47f-e8a95f2342d9/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tyro/extras/__init__.py:5
      1 """The :mod:`tyro.extras` submodule contains helpers that complement :func:`tyro.cli()`.
      2 
      3 Compared to the core interface, APIs here are more likely to be changed or deprecated. """
----> 5 from .._argparse_formatter import set_accent_color as set_accent_color
      6 from .._cli import get_parser as get_parser
      7 from ._base_configs import (
      8     subcommand_type_from_defaults as subcommand_type_from_defaults,
      9 )

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-8a237d14-25f4-4066-b47f-e8a95f2342d9/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tyro/_argparse_formatter.py:37
     35 from rich.text import Text
     36 from rich.theme import Theme
---> 37 from typing_extensions import override
     39 from . import _arguments, _strings, conf
     40 from ._parsers import ParserSpecification

ImportError: cannot import name 'override' from 'typing_extensions' (/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/typing_extensions.py)
```

I have tried installing multiple versions of typing_extensions, both the most updated version (4.8.0), as well as (4.7.1) as was suggested in [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77074676/importerror-cannot-import-name-deprecated-from-typing-extensions). I also tried the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72980064/from-typing-extensions-import-paramspec-importerror-cannot-import-name-paramsp), as well as installing the dependencies with '%' instead of '!', as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77316896/importerror-cannot-import-name-override-from-typing-extensions). None of this has worked.

Here's a full list of my installed packages:

```
Package                      Version
---------------------------- -------------
absl-py                      1.0.0
accelerate                   0.25.0.dev0
aiohttp                      3.8.5
aiosignal                    1.3.1
anyio                        3.5.0
appdirs                      1.4.4
argon2-cffi                  21.3.0
argon2-cffi-bindings         21.2.0
astor                        0.8.1
asttokens                    2.2.1
astunparse                   1.6.3
async-timeout                4.0.3
attrs                        21.4.0
audioread                    3.0.0
azure-core                   1.29.1
azure-cosmos                 4.3.1
azure-storage-blob           12.17.0
azure-storage-file-datalake  12.12.0
backcall                     0.2.0
bcrypt                       3.2.0
beautifulsoup4               4.11.1
bitsandbytes                 0.41.2.post2
black                        22.6.0
bleach                       4.1.0
blinker                      1.4
blis                         0.7.10
boto3                        1.24.28
botocore                     1.27.28
cachetools                   4.2.4
catalogue                    2.0.9
category-encoders            2.6.1
certifi                      2022.9.14
cffi                         1.15.1
chardet                      4.0.0
charset-normalizer           2.0.4
click                        8.0.4
cloudpickle                  2.0.0
cmdstanpy                    1.1.0
confection                   0.1.1
configparser                 5.2.0
convertdate                  2.4.0
cryptography                 37.0.1
cycler                       0.11.0
cymem                        2.0.7
Cython                       0.29.32
dacite                       1.8.1
databricks-automl-runtime    0.2.17
databricks-cli               0.17.7
databricks-feature-store     0.14.1
databricks-sdk               0.1.6
dataclasses-json             0.5.14
datasets                     2.13.1
dbl-tempo                    0.1.23
dbus-python                  1.2.18
debugpy                      1.6.0
decorator                    5.1.1
defusedxml                   0.7.1
dill                         0.3.4
diskcache                    5.6.1
distlib                      0.3.7
distro                       1.7.0
distro-info                  1.1+ubuntu0.1
docstring-parser             0.15
docstring-to-markdown        0.12
einops                       0.6.1
entrypoints                  0.4
ephem                        4.1.4
evaluate                     0.4.0
executing                    1.2.0
facets-overview              1.0.3
fastapi                      0.98.0
fastjsonschema               2.18.0
fasttext                     0.9.2
filelock                     3.6.0
flash-attn                   1.0.7
Flask                        1.1.2+db1
flatbuffers                  23.5.26
fonttools                    4.25.0
frozenlist                   1.4.0
fsspec                       2022.7.1
future                       0.18.2
gast                         0.4.0
gitdb                        4.0.10
GitPython                    3.1.27
google-api-core              2.8.2
google-auth                  1.33.0
google-auth-oauthlib         0.4.6
google-cloud-core            2.3.3
google-cloud-storage         2.10.0
google-crc32c                1.5.0
google-pasta                 0.2.0
google-resumable-media       2.5.0
googleapis-common-protos     1.56.4
greenlet                     1.1.1
grpcio                       1.48.1
grpcio-status                1.48.1
gunicorn                     20.1.0
gviz-api                     1.10.0
h11                          0.14.0
h5py                         3.7.0
holidays                     0.27.1
horovod                      0.28.1
htmlmin                      0.1.12
httplib2                     0.20.2
httptools                    0.6.0
huggingface-hub              0.16.4
idna                         3.3
ImageHash                    4.3.1
imbalanced-learn             0.10.1
importlib-metadata           4.11.3
importlib-resources          6.0.1
ipykernel                    6.17.1
ipython                      8.10.0
ipython-genutils             0.2.0
ipywidgets                   7.7.2
isodate                      0.6.1
itsdangerous                 2.0.1
jedi                         0.18.1
jeepney                      0.7.1
Jinja2                       2.11.3
jmespath                     0.10.0
joblib                       1.2.0
joblibspark                  0.5.1
jsonschema                   4.16.0
jupyter-client               7.3.4
jupyter_core                 4.11.2
jupyterlab-pygments          0.1.2
jupyterlab-widgets           1.0.0
keras                        2.11.0
keyring                      23.5.0
kiwisolver                   1.4.2
langchain                    0.0.217
langchainplus-sdk            0.0.20
langcodes                    3.3.0
launchpadlib                 1.10.16
lazr.restfulclient           0.14.4
lazr.uri                     1.0.6
lazy_loader                  0.3
libclang                     15.0.6.1
librosa                      0.10.0
lightgbm                     3.3.5
llvmlite                     0.38.0
LunarCalendar                0.0.9
Mako                         1.2.0
Markdown                     3.3.4
markdown-it-py               3.0.0
MarkupSafe                   2.0.1
marshmallow                  3.20.1
matplotlib                   3.5.2
matplotlib-inline            0.1.6
mccabe                       0.7.0
mdurl                        0.1.2
mistune                      0.8.4
mleap                        0.20.0
mlflow-skinny                2.5.0
more-itertools               8.10.0
msgpack                      1.0.5
multidict                    6.0.4
multimethod                  1.9.1
multiprocess                 0.70.12.2
murmurhash                   1.0.9
mypy-extensions              0.4.3
nbclient                     0.5.13
nbconvert                    6.4.4
nbformat                     5.5.0
nest-asyncio                 1.5.5
networkx                     2.8.4
ninja                        1.11.1
nltk                         3.7
nodeenv                      1.8.0
notebook                     6.4.12
numba                        0.55.1
numexpr                      2.8.4
numpy                        1.21.5
oauthlib                     3.2.0
openai                       0.27.8
openapi-schema-pydantic      1.2.4
opt-einsum                   3.3.0
packaging                    21.3
pandas                       1.4.4
pandocfilters                1.5.0
paramiko                     2.9.2
parso                        0.8.3
pathspec                     0.9.0
pathy                        0.10.2
patsy                        0.5.2
peft                         0.4.0
petastorm                    0.12.1
pexpect                      4.8.0
phik                         0.12.3
pickleshare                  0.7.5
Pillow                       9.2.0
pip                          23.3.1
platformdirs                 2.5.2
plotly                       5.9.0
pluggy                       1.0.0
pmdarima                     2.0.3
pooch                        1.7.0
preshed                      3.0.8
prompt-toolkit               3.0.36
prophet                      1.1.4
protobuf                     3.19.4
psutil                       5.9.0
psycopg2                     2.9.3
ptyprocess                   0.7.0
pure-eval                    0.2.2
pyarrow                      8.0.0
pyasn1                       0.4.8
pyasn1-modules               0.2.8
pybind11                     2.11.1
pycparser                    2.21
pydantic                     1.10.6
pyflakes                     3.0.1
Pygments                     2.16.1
PyGObject                    3.42.1
PyJWT                        2.3.0
PyMeeus                      0.5.12
PyNaCl                       1.5.0
pyodbc                       4.0.32
pyparsing                    3.0.9
pyright                      1.1.294
pyrsistent                   0.18.0
pytesseract                  0.3.10
python-apt                   2.4.0+ubuntu2
python-dateutil              2.8.2
python-dotenv                1.0.0
python-editor                1.0.4
python-lsp-jsonrpc           1.0.0
python-lsp-server            1.7.1
pytoolconfig                 1.2.2
pytz                         2022.1
PyWavelets                   1.3.0
PyYAML                       6.0
pyzmq                        23.2.0
regex                        2022.7.9
requests                     2.28.1
requests-oauthlib            1.3.1
responses                    0.18.0
rich                         13.6.0
rope                         1.7.0
rsa                          4.9
s3transfer                   0.6.0
safetensors                  0.3.2
scikit-learn                 1.1.1
scipy                        1.9.1
seaborn                      0.11.2
SecretStorage                3.3.1
Send2Trash                   1.8.0
sentence-transformers        2.2.2
sentencepiece                0.1.99
setuptools                   63.4.1
shap                         0.41.0
shtab                        1.6.4
simplejson                   3.17.6
six                          1.16.0
slicer                       0.0.7
smart-open                   5.2.1
smmap                        5.0.0
sniffio                      1.2.0
soundfile                    0.12.1
soupsieve                    2.3.1
soxr                         0.3.6
spacy                        3.5.3
spacy-legacy                 3.0.12
spacy-loggers                1.0.4
spark-tensorflow-distributor 1.0.0
SQLAlchemy                   1.4.39
sqlparse                     0.4.2
srsly                        2.4.7
ssh-import-id                5.11
stack-data                   0.6.2
starlette                    0.27.0
statsmodels                  0.13.2
tabulate                     0.8.10
tangled-up-in-unicode        0.2.0
tenacity                     8.1.0
tensorboard                  2.11.0
tensorboard-data-server      0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-profile   2.11.2
tensorboard-plugin-wit       1.8.1
tensorflow                   2.11.1
tensorflow-estimator         2.11.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem 0.33.0
termcolor                    2.3.0
terminado                    0.13.1
testpath                     0.6.0
thinc                        8.1.12
threadpoolctl                2.2.0
tiktoken                     0.4.0
tokenize-rt                  4.2.1
tokenizers                   0.13.3
tomli                        2.0.1
torch                        1.13.1+cu117
torchvision                  0.14.1+cu117
tornado                      6.1
tqdm                         4.64.1
traitlets                    5.1.1
transformers                 4.30.2
trl                          0.7.4
typeguard                    2.13.3
typer                        0.7.0
typing_extensions            4.7.1
typing-inspect               0.9.0
tyro                         0.5.14
ujson                        5.4.0
unattended-upgrades          0.1
urllib3                      1.26.11
uvicorn                      0.23.2
uvloop                       0.17.0
virtualenv                   20.16.3
visions                      0.7.5
wadllib                      1.3.6
wasabi                       1.1.2
watchfiles                   0.19.0
wcwidth                      0.2.5
webencodings                 0.5.1
websocket-client             0.58.0
websockets                   11.0.3
Werkzeug                     2.0.3
whatthepatch                 1.0.2
wheel                        0.37.1
widgetsnbextension           3.6.1
wordcloud                    1.9.2
wrapt                        1.14.1
xgboost                      1.7.6
xxhash                       3.3.0
yapf                         0.31.0
yarl                         1.9.2
ydata-profiling              4.2.0
zipp                         3.8.0
```

If anyone has any idea how to fix this, please let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

might related to Databricks bug. see this, https://github.com/openai/openai-python/issues/751

Comment: Yes, I believe it is a databricks bug :/

Answer (score 1):

Either depreciated is declared in typing_extensions.py or it isn't - open up typing_extensions.py and view the code.

Try opening up python and just execute:
from typing_extensions import deprecated

and check your sys.path

If it is class depreciated is declared, then you have a python environment "clash". A typical scenario is your dev/debug environment pointing at different directories to the system environment.